# pygame player is not updating

Tags: python, pygame

So I have this small piece of code, and it runs fine, but when i move the character, wherever the character was before, theres a picture of it behind it.  imagine it as taking a pencil and drawing on a piece of paper, and thats basically how its showing up.  I don't know where the code is wrong as it runs fine otherwise.  It has this problem with any other way to display the player. Help?

```
import pygame,sys,os
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init


MOVERATE = 8
WINDOWWIDTH = 1000
WINDOWHEIGHT = 1000
def terminate():
     pygame.quit()
     sys.exit()

playerImage = pygame.image.load('Test_Block.png')
playerRect = playerImage.get_rect()

WHITE = (255,255,255)

WindowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.update()


WindowSurface.fill(WHITE)
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()



pygame.display.update()
while True:

 playerRect.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH /3, WINDOWHEIGHT / 3)
 moveLeft = moveRight = moveUp = moveDown = False


 while True:

      for event in pygame.event.get():
           if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()


           if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                      if event.key == ord('a'):
                          moveRight = False
                          moveLeft = True
                      if event.key == ord('d'):
                          moveLeft = False
                          moveRight = True
                      if event.key == ord('w'):
                          moveDown = False
                          moveUp = True
                      if event.key == ord('s'):
                          moveUp = False
                          moveDown = True

           if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.type == K_ESCAPE:
                     terminate()
                if event.key == ord('a'):
                     moveLeft = False
                if event.key == ord('d'):
                     moveRight = False
                if event.key == ord('w'):
                     moveUp = False
                if event.key == ord('s'):
                     moveDown = False
           pygame.display.update()

      if moveLeft and playerRect.left > 0:
           playerRect.move_ip(-1 * MOVERATE,0)
      if moveRight and playerRect.right < WINDOWWIDTH:
           playerRect.move_ip(MOVERATE,0)
      if moveUp and playerRect.top >0:
           playerRect.move_ip(0,-1 * MOVERATE)
      if moveDown and playerRect.bottom < WINDOWHEIGHT:
           playerRect.move_ip(0,MOVERATE)

           pygame.display.update()

      WindowSurface.blit(playerImage, playerRect)
      pygame.display.update()
      mainClock.tick(30)
pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fill the screen with white to erase the old image. Use `WindowSurface.fill(WHITE)` in your code right before  `WindowSurface.blit(playerImage, playerRect)` at the same indentation.